# 2 Classes with same namespace in laravel/PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I'm confused with the workflow in laravel/PHP. I have 2 files with different name, but same namespace.

Files:

**HomeController.php**

> Namespace: namespace App\Http\Controllers;
>
> Class name: HomeController

**HomeController_old.php**

> Namespace: namespace App\Http\Controllers;
>
> Class name: HomeController

The problem is, it always use the old one that I've created instead of the new controller file. Any idea?

**UPDATE**

**Problem**

- When I edit a method in `HomeController.php`, example: `create()` method, my changes doesn't do anything, but when I edit that method in `HomeController_old.php`, my changes works.

Comment: your class name should be HomeController_old instead of HomeController. The namespace is fine.. the namespace usually indicate folder path. the class name should be diff

Comment: Because you are using the same class name.

Comment: @Widada So, why is it using the old one instead of the new one that I've just created?

Comment: @ZeroOne Do you know the reason why it is using the old one?

Comment: I think OP's question is, why would the autoloader load `HomeController` from `HomeController_old.php` instead of `HomeController.php` but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Phil exactly, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Jonjie could you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61583779/edit) to clarify what you're asking? Also explain how you're verifying this problem; how do you know it's loading from the `_old.php` file?

Comment: The reason of the use of the old one insted of the new one is because the old one was created before the new one with the same class name, to fix this  use  ´composer dump autoload´ command.

Comment: @Phil Please check my update.

Comment: @rüff0 Please add your answer so I can give you the right answer.

Comment: @rüff0 that probably explains it but why would any PSR autoload scheme pick up a file with the `_old.php` suffix?

Comment: @Phil cause was the first created file with that classname inside. you can change the name of the file as much as you want and if you dont change the classname the autoload will still looking in the new renamed file. even if you rename the file and then create another file with the same name.. the autoload will search for the class in the renamed file.

Comment: What I mean is that if OP's classname is `HomeController`, there's no autoloader scheme that would ever map that to `HomeController_old.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of the use of the old one insted of the new one is because the old one was created before the new one with the same class name, to fix this use

```
composer dump autoload
```